# Stretch div to fit it's content

Tags: html, css

I tried already all solutions over the internet and not worked for me. I want to make a 'content' div and a 'side' div inside a 'wrap' div and bellow of 'wrap to be a footer div. If I add more text inside 'content', div grow and fit it's content, and push footer down. Same thing with 'side'. I made a jsfiddle.net/h97t9me4/4 to illustrate but it's using a table instead of divs. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: we need some example code/attempt to see a better view of what you want.

Comment: Can you post some of the things you tried?

Comment: Sorry. I added jsfiddle link.

Comment: Here is a cheap way to do what you ask: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/h97t9me4/5/ I've changed your table, tr, td into divs with class names same as the previous tag (table, tr, td respectively) and then changed their display property appropriately. So `<table>` becomes `<div class="table">` and in the css I added `.table{display:table;}`

Comment: I got it, awesome! 2 days I tried all i could. @ctwheels

Comment: This link will give you more information about the css display property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wDnsr

HTML

```
    <div class="content">
        <p>This is the content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="side">
        <p>This is the side</p>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <p>This is the footer</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
    width: 75%;
    padding: 1em;
    float: left;
}

.side {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 1em;
    float: left;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    clear: left;
}
```